# Examples of CLR compiler optimizations

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, clr, compiler-optimization

I'm doing a presentation in few months about .Net performance and optimization, I wanted to provide some samples of unnecessary optimization, things that will be done by the compiler anyways.

where can I find some explanation on what optimizations the compiler is actually capable of maybe some before and after code?

Comment: Aren't the CLR and the JVM(s with JIT) performing most optimizations at runtime/ duringJIT-compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out these links

1. [C# Compiler Optimizations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/07/04/c-compiler-optimization.aspx)
2. [compiler optimization](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx)
3. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0hfscdc.aspx)

Also checkout this book on MSIL
1. **Microsoft Intermediate Language: Comparison Between C# and VB.NET / Niranjan Kumar**

Answer (score 1):

What I think would be even better than examples of "things that will be done by the compiler anyways" would be examples of scenarios where the compiler *doesn't* perform "optimizations" that the developer *assumes* will yield a performance improvement but which, in fact, won't.

For example sometimes a developer will assume that caching a value locally will improve performance, when actually the savings of having one less value on the stack outweighs the miniscule cost of a field access that can be inlined.

Or the developer might assume that "force-inlining" a method call (essentially by stripping out the call itself and replacing with copied/pasted code) will be worthwhile, when in reality keeping the method call as-is would result in its getting inlined by the compiler only when it makes sense (when the benefit of inlining outweighs the growth in code size).

This is only a general idea, of course. I don't have concrete code samples that I can point to; but maybe you can scrounge some up if you look for them.