# IF statement, difference between IF NOT ...False Vs IF TRUE

Tags: vba, if-statement

I want to clarify VBA IF statement. What is the difference between them:

```
if x=true then
'do something at true
end if

if NOT x=false then
' do something at true
end if
```

Both statements will check same conditions. What is the difference among them.

To be more specific I am working on recordset object adodb and trying to find the difference between these and can't figure out

```
If Not objMyRecordset.EOF=True Then
' do something when objMyRecordset.EOF is not true (Implicitly means False)
End if

If objMyRecordset.EOF=False Then
' do something when objMyRecordset.EOF returns False (implicitly means not True)
End if
```

Both If's are checking same condition here too. But on numerous articles on internet I found the test condition with `If Not objMyRecordset.EOF=True Then`. There must be some real reason behind this. can someone explain?

Regards

Comment: `If Not False` equals `If True` and also `If Not True` equals `If False`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: No need for `True` and `False`. If you deal with a `Boolean`, simply write `If x Then` or `If Not x Then`.

Comment: You will see `If Not obj Is Nothing` testing if an object is instantiated because `Is Something` is not a keyword.  We can't test if an object is something, we can only test if it is not nothing.  In the case of dictionaries, you can test if a key exists with `If dict.Exists(key)` but this will create the key if it doesn't already exist; that does not happen when using `If Not dict.Exists(key)`

Comment: ProfoundlyOblivious, as far as I understood is sometimes we need to test if something exists but there is no keyword for that time's 'exists' so we check the opposite, negation of (if something not exists) will return required result. But what for the case where I have possibility to check both ways, like my question about  recordsets. I can test both cases. I came across a lot like "If Not objMyRecordset.EOF=True" while it is working other way too "If objMyRecordset.EOF=False" as there any real benefit in such scenario?

Comment: You should use is  "If Not rs.EOF Then " - there's no need for a true or false because EOF is  itself Boolean. The styles you are seeing is where people are copying this without understanding and adding a True or false. Strictly speaking the routine  "If rs.EOF Then 'do nothing ELSE 'do something  " is slightly more efficient then "If Not rs.EOF then 'do something" because the Not requires an extra clock cycle - but that's less important these days than it once was.

Comment: Sunny,  no "real benefit" exists between `Is` vs `Not Is` [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818933/is-ifvar-true-faster-than-ifvar-false) and the speed of `If`  [might surprise you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive)  Dropping the equivalence test (don't use `If True = True`, use `If True`) and using `False` instead `Not True` may be  faster **but** a well named variable in a context that makes your code more enjoyable to read and easier to understand is far more important than an imperceivable speed difference. If nanoseconds matter, don't use VBA.

Comment: "ProfoundlyOblivious" and "Harassed Dad" your comments satisfies me. No idea how to mark my question as answered.